# How to get managed_file value url?

Tags: 8

I'm trying to add a front page image as part of the theme setting. And so far I'm able to upload the image; however, I need to be able to get this in preprocess function so I can use the in my templates.

Here is what I got so far

**casper.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function casper_preprocess_page(&$variables){
    $variables['frontpage_background_image'] = theme_get_setting('frontpage_background_image', 'casper');
    kint($variables['frontpage_background_image']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function casper_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, &$theme) {
    _casper_theme_settings($form, $form_state, $theme);
}

 function _casper_theme_settings(&$form, &$form_state){
       $form['theme_extra']['frontpage_background_image'] = array(
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#title' => 'Front Page Background Image',
        '#description' => 'Add background image for the front page',
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
        '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('frontpage_background_image' , 'casper'),
        '#upload_validators' => array(
            'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
        ),
    );
}
```

And here is the kint results

[image]

So my question is what I'm doing wrong ? What should I do to get the URL instead of a number ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your field only stores the file ID, so it makes sense that theme_get_settings only returns a number. If I'm not mistaken, this should work:

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
function casper_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  // Get the value of the first element in the array.
  $fid = reset(theme_get_setting('frontpage_background_image', 'casper'));
  // Load the file.
  $file = File::load($fid);
  // Generate the URL.
  $variables['frontpage_background_image'] = $file->url();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, File incorrectly overrides url() to return the URL to the file. In file_entity, we override that override because then files do have a real canonical URL that is needed for e.g. REST integration. I'd recommend to use file_create_url($file->getFileUri()) instead.

Comment: @Berdir I'm not sure if I completely understand what you're saying. According to the [api documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Entity!File.php/function/File%3A%3Aurl/8), `file_create_url($this->getFileUri())` is exactly what File::url() does. How does doing that manually make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does in core. But that's a very different behavior from all other url() implementations, where it returns the canonical link/route of that entity. It also completely disregards the $rel and other arguments. Files in core have no such thing, so someone thought it would be a good idea to return the next-best-thing. However, in file_entity, there's file/ID, file/ID/edit and so on. So we override that method again and revert it to the original behavior of the parent class. Also note that url() is actually deprecated in 8.0.0 in favor of toUrl() (which File doesn't override).

Comment: @Berdir Thanks for the explanation. So for those who like a td;dr... You would recommend `$variables['frontpage_background_image'] = $file->toUrl();`, right? (I guess we should update the answer if that is the recommended approach.)

Comment: No. file_create_url($this->getFileUri()), as I said :) toUrl() returns a Url object and in case of file, it would actually throw an exception in core.

Answer (score 0):

I've merged the answer provided by marcvangend & suggestion provided by Berdir.

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $facebook_icon = theme_get_setting('facebook_icon', 'mytheme');
  if (!empty($facebook_icon)) {
    $fid = reset($facebook_icon);
    $file = File::load($fid);
    $variables['facebook_icon'] = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
  }
}
```